# Problems with Compiling C program on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu-10.10

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 as VM and am new to it. Until recently i could easily compile C programs from the terminal. However, as i try to compile them now it gives a message as:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have searched for it over the net but could not figure out what is going wrong. I know the answer to it must be simple but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems `libc.a` is missing.

Comment: Are you compiling directly or via a build tool like `make`? If it's the former, then show us how.

Comment: Am compiling it directly. Its this way : gcc Test.c -o Test
for any file, say Test.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the necessary tools should solve your problem. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably -- most of us do -- installed Ubuntu desktop, but not Ubuntu server. A whole lot of tools don't come over with a default Ubuntu desktop installation.

So start by installing build-essential:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
```

Then try the compile again. build-essential contains a bunch of components that you need to perform a basic compile.

For my work, beyond build-essential, I have to install other libraries like curses. However, I first have to have build-essential installed before I can do anything else.